# Joomla sql query not working

Tags: php, sql, joomla

can someone tell me what is wrong with this? It comes up empty when there is something there, the names in the fields are all correct:

```
if($token = JRequest::getVar('token')){
$getImgQuery = 'SELECT adimage FROM #__chronoforms_data_adsList WHERE cf_uid = ' . $token;
$db->setQuery( $getImgQuery );
$imagename = $db->loadResult();
echo $imagename;
$fullimgpath = "adimages/" . $imagename;
}
```

I'm using this in an article, just below it I have some more code that works:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM #__chronoforms_data_adsList WHERE cf_user_id = ' . $userid;
$db->setQuery( $query );
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($result as $x){
//loop through everything including adimage
}
```

I've been trying to figure it out for hours but I can't seem to get it to work, it's driving me nutz.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i can think of is that your query evaluates to no rows at all... Have you tried printing it out and running it out in phpmyadmin to validate that it DOES return something and that there is no errors in your SQL query that you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($token = JRequest::getVar('token')){
```

Assuming you want to set $token to the variable returned by getVar (and $token doesn't contain an existing value that you want to compare with `==`), then I'd take a look the other [parameters taken by getVar](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Environment/JRequest.html#getVar) and check it's returning what you're expecting e.g. specify $hash and return $type.

To debug the query I'd add this line after loadResult()

```
print_r( $db );
```

In the output, look for any error messages and run the translated _sql query manually to check the query works as expected.